# Carousel - setas como paginação

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl

Estou trabalhando com o *Owl Carousel v2.2.1* e preciso sejam exibidas 3 imagens de cada vez. Isso já é possível usando a paginação, mas eu preciso que o mesmo evento seja feito usando as setas. Toda vez que clicar na seta deve mudar a página (aparecer as próximas 3 imagens).

Tentei usar a opção `sliderBy` e também `scrollPerPage: true`, mas não funcionou, apenas faz o *loop* com a próxima imagem.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Se possível poste seu código para auxiliar o entendimento da questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a opção `slideBy` (**[veja doc.](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)**).

O valor padrão do `slideBy` é `1`, ou seja, a cada clique nas setas, o slide irá *avançar/voltar* 1 item. Ao setar `3`, irá *avançar/voltar* de 3 em 3 itens.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
   owl.owlCarousel({
      margin: 10,
      nav: true,
      loop: true,
      slideBy: 3
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>
 <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="item">
     <h4>1</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>2</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>3</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>4</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>5</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>6</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>7</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>8</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>9</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>10</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>11</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <h4>12</h4>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @dvd  agora consegui utilizar esta opção.